# How can use config section in rebus 2?

Tags: config, app-config, rebus

I'm trying to configure rebus using app.config. This lines are working in older versions of rebus, but in the new version (Rebus 2) it does not work.

```
.Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
.MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
```

What are the equivalent ones in rebus 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent for the queue name and worker configuration in Rebus 2.

You *can* configure your endpoint mappings with the [`Rebus.XmlConfig`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.XmlConfig/) package by going

```
Configure.With(...)
    (...)
    .Routing(t => t.AddEndpointMappingsFromAppConfig())
    (...)
```

though.

Maybe there will be some way of picking up settings from `app.config`/`web.config` in the future - but the configuration thing is one big thing that I know will not be portable to .NET core if it's based on `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, so I intentionally left it out.